# Duvida PHP + Sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

Boa Tarde pessoal

sou novo aqui no fórum então não sei se abri esse tópico no local certo.

preciso de uma ajuda em uma tabela que estou gerando com php através de algumas consultas sendo uma em mysql, e a partir do resultado dela realizo outra em um bd sql server utilizando o odbc_exec.

a tabela lista os produtos que estão disponível produção na fabrica e busca no banco de dados do erp a quantidade total do produto em estoque( para ajudar a decidir oque irá produzir primeiro) o problema é que para alguns produtos ele  traz o estoque certinho e para outros não.  coloquei para escrever o sql(do sql server) na tela, copiei o codigo e executei direto no bd pelo ssms (SQL Server Management Studio) e traz o resultado normalmente. no entanto se executo o php, para uns registros aparece e para outros não.

abaixo segue o código:

```
       <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed  lista-clientes">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>CORTE</th>
                    <th>GRUPO</th>
                    <th>SUBGRUPO</th>
                    <th>ESTAMPA</th>
                    <th>TAMANHO</th>
                   <th>DISPONIVEL</th>                    
                    <th>ESTOQUE</th>
                    <th>DISP. P/ PROD.</th>
                 </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
<?php 
$sql="select * from corte where status='Novo'";

$executa=mysqli_query($link, $sql);

while($ROW= mysqli_fetch_assoc($executa)){ 

//BUSCA DADOS DO CORTE
    $SQL_DADOS_SEQUENCIAL="SELECT * FROM sequencial WHERE CORTE='".$ROW['CORTE']."'";
    $EXECUTA_DADOS_SEQUENCIAL=mysqli_QUERY($link,$SQL_DADOS_SEQUENCIAL);
    $RESULTADO_DADOS_SEQUENCIAL=mysqli_fetch_assoc($EXECUTA_DADOS_SEQUENCIAL);
//busca os dados do sequencial
$sql_busca_dados_corte="select * from sequencial where CORTE='".$ROW['CORTE']."'";
$executa_busca_corte=mysqli_query($link, $sql_busca_dados_corte);
$exibe_busca_corte=mysqli_fetch_assoc($executa_busca_corte);

//MONTA NOME DO PRODUTO
$ESPACO=" ";
$NOME_PRODUTO=$ROW['GRUPO'];
$NOME_PRODUTO.=$ESPACO;
$NOME_PRODUTO.=$ROW['SUBGRUPO'];
$NOME_PRODUTO.=$ESPACO;
$NOME_PRODUTO.= $RESULTADO_DADOS_SEQUENCIAL['cor_estampa'];

//busca o codigo do produto pelo nome cor e tamanho
$SQL_BUSCA_CODIGO="SELECT sum(c.ES3)as tam
FROM PRODUTOS A 
left JOIN PRODUTO_CORES B 
ON A.PRODUTO = B.PRODUTO
left join ESTOQUE_PRODUTOS c
ON A.PRODUTO = c.PRODUTO
WHERE A.DESC_PRODUTO LIKE'%".TRIM($NOME_PRODUTO)."%' AND B.COR_PRODUTO='".TRIM($RESULTADO_DADOS_SEQUENCIAL['tecido'])."'";
$resultado_BUSCA_CODIGO = odbc_exec($con_sql, $SQL_BUSCA_CODIGO);
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . nl2br( $ROW['CORTE']) . "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . nl2br( $ROW['GRUPO']) . "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . nl2br( $ROW['SUBGRUPO']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td>" . nl2br( $exibe_busca_corte['cor_estampa']) . "</td>"; 

echo "<td>" . nl2br( $ROW['TAMANHO']) . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . nl2br( $ROW['QUANTIDADE']) . "</td>";
echo "<td>". odbc_result($resultado_BUSCA_CODIGO,"tam")."</td>";
echo "<td>" .  $SQL_BUSCA_CODIGO . "</td>";

}//fim while 


?>

        </tbody>
        </table>
```

já tentei varias soluções mas não consegui, pf me ajuda ai galera

Comment: o que que a variável `$resultado_BUSCA_CODIGO` esta a te retornar ?

Comment: ela faz a consulta dentro do bd, ai eu uso a função odbc_result pra exibir